# Moq mocked object is null when running MSTest from command line

Tags: unit-testing, command-line, moq, mstest, nullreferenceexception

A .NET Core MSTest unit test that passes when I run it in Visual Studio is failing when I run it from the command line using the command "dotnet test" (not passing any arguments).  I'm getting the error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

It's failing because a dependency that I've mocked using Moq is null.  At first I thought that the issue might have something to do with the test in Visual Studio being run with loose mocks and then for some reason being run with strict mocks from the command line, this turned out to be false as even when I got the test passing in Visual Studio with strict mocks it was still failing from the command line.

Comment: Can you please share with us some sample unit tests that are failing? Could you please highlight in which line does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was being an idiot.  The dll I was running against was an outdated file that preceded me changing the name of the test project.  Thanks Peter Csala for making me look a bit closer at the unit test that was failing, it made me realise that the failing unit test no longer exists in my code, making me realise the dll was outdated.